# How to fix error of compiling the smart contract: Invalid number of parameters for "undefined"?

Tags: contract-development, truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-compile

I want to compile a simple smart contract using truffle.

my smart contract `SimpleStorage.sol`

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.7.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    int public sensorData;
    constructor(int _sensorData) public {
        sensorData = _sensorData;
    }
    function setsensorData(int _sensorData) public {
        sensorData = _sensorData;
    }
    function getsensorData() view public returns (int) {
        return sensorData;
    }
}
```

`2_deploy_contracts.js`

```
var SimpleStorage = artifacts.require("SimpleStorage");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage);
};
```

However, I could this error:

```
"SimpleStorage" -- Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1!.
```

I have tried this, but it does not work too:

```
var SimpleStorage = artifacts.require("SimpleStorage");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage, sensorData);
};
```

My versions:

```
Truffle v5.1.31 (core: 5.1.31)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v10.21.0
Web3.js v1.2.1
```

Could you please give a feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Your contract requires one constructor parameter, so you have to provide that when deploying.

Your second code sample should work if the `sensorData` variable is of integer type. Or, better yet, of BigNumber type. So create the variable `sensorData` as BigNumber and pass it to the deployer just like you already do. If you're using web3.js , check out more info here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#bn